# What does "it" refer to and the meaning of "take up" in this context?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> Pakistan said that with the support of China, *it* will **take up** India's unilateral actions in Kashmir with the U.N. Security Council and may approach the U.N. Human Rights Commission over what *it* says is the "genocide" of the Kashmiri people.

What do these *it*s refer to and what does **take up** mean in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The antecedent of "it", here is "Pakistan". The text says that Pakistan will take up the matter with the Security Council.

["Take up"](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/take-up_1) is a phrasal verb with many meanings, and this is closest to sense 5 inn the linked def. To "take up a matter with someone" is to raise or discuss that matter with that person, or if it is a group or body, to raise it before the body, or put it on their agenda.